# Write down general term of function, divide by zero?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to find the general term of this function.

[image]

The answer given is [image]

But this looks like it doesn't work when n=0 because we would have to divide by zero, when the first term is clearly 1. Is there a simple explanation?

Comment: In the formula, if n starts at 0, the sequence doesn't work because it requires you to divide by zero. That can't be right because the first term is 1

Comment: If you want a formula for the general term that works for all $n$, you can use the [Kronecker delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta): $f(x) = \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x+2)^{n}}{3^{n}(n + \delta_{0,n})}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest explanation is that the formula you give just doesn't work for n=0, the term is different form the others in the expansion.

Comment: Why would this be the answer if it doesn't work for everything? I guess I was wondering if a "general term" didn't necessarily work for all values of n, and only the majority

Comment: If you look to it that way, the answer is wrong. But normally you can just say it is the formula for the general term if only the first one doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. Learning series/sequences seems more difficult because everything seems less structured to me.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I see that the only thing which is wrong is the wrong use of linguistic terms.

In particular, it's not suitable to say $\frac{(x+2)^n}{3^n n}$ the "General Term of Function".

If it were something general, then it should give us the very $1^{st}$ term of the expansion for $0 \leq n < 1, n \in \mathbb W$ but it is not doing so and therefore, it should be said only "A general term which can calculate the terms for every $n \in \mathbb N$.

Be careful that the picture, you mentioned, is not telling that it is the General Term of the Function but you yourself are thinking it in wrong way.

**Note that** the following propositions may or may not contain a general term.

$1 + 3 + 5 + ... + \overbrace {2n-1}=n^2, \forall n \in \mathbb N$

$1 + 3 + 5 + ... + \overbrace{2n-1}=n^2, \forall n \in \mathbb W$

> The terms, I assert to be general are over braced. Can you tell me where using the word "general term" is true? Either for the first proposition or next one?